# Iterating through XML file using JDOM Return NullPointerException?

Tags: java, xml, loops, dom, nullpointerexception

I want to iterate through `XML file` using `JDOM` and I get a `NullPointerException` in line 67 on my code, I try to store the `XML date` into a `List`:

```
public class ProduitImportXml {


public static List<Produit> getProduits() {

    List<Produit> produitsList = new ArrayList<Produit>();

    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("ProduitData.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); // optional --------

        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("produits");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element el = (Element) nNode;
                int len = nNode.getChildNodes().getLength();

                for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
                {

                            Produit p=new Produit(
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("idProduit").item(0).getTextContent(),//return NullPointerException 
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent(), 
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("marque").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("modele").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("libelle").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("codeTac").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                    el.getElementsByTagName("genCode").item(0).getTextContent());

                            produitsList.add(p);


                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 
    return produitsList;
}
}
```

Any idea about how to solve this problem, this is the console message that I catch:

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Highlight which code is at line 67.

Comment: `Produit p=new Produit(                                el.getElementsByTagName("idProduit").item(0).getTextContent()`